# In which cases, I should use Capture rather than an object in Unit Test with EasyMock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, capture, easymock

I am not sure in which cases I should use EasyMock Capture when doing Unit Test.
I have read some materials on the website but I am not sure my understanding is correct.

To use below code for example:

```
public class UserService {

    private UserDao userDao;

    public boolean register() {

        User user = new User();
        user.type = "VIP";

        return userDao.insertUser(user);
    }
}

public class UserServiceTest {

    public void testRegister {

        UserDao userDao = createMock(UserDao.class);
        Capture<User> captureUser = new Capture<>();

        expect(userDao.insertUser(capture(captureUser)))
            .andReturn(true);
        replay(userDao);

        userService.setUserDao(userDao);
        userService.register();

        verify(userDao);
    }
}
```

1. Should I use the Capture in this case: Because the user object is created inside the register() method, and it is the argument for userDao.insertUser(user). So, I need to use Capture for it?
2. Is that means: When I want to test   testTargetClass.testTargetMethod(). If 
   there is another service call inside the testTargetMethod() and its arguments were created inside the testTargetMethod(), I should use the Capture for the arguments?
3. Could I use below code to test it?

   public void testRegister {

   ```
   UserDao userDao = createMock(UserDao.class);

   User mockUser = new User();
   mockUser.setType = "VIP";

   expect(userDao.insertUser(mockUser)).andReturn(true);
   replay(userDao);

   userService.setUserDao(userDao);
   userService.register();

   verify(userDao);
   ```

   }

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to verify a parameter, you have two choices.

1. Use a matcher. Like `userDao.insertUser(same(user))`
2. Use a capture

When testing the parameter is easy (like testing identity, equality and so on), the matcher will work perfectly and should be preferred.

When testing the parameter is harder. You would like to check multiple attributes for instance, the capture will make it much easier. You will do

```
User user = capturedUser.getValue();
assertEquals("name", user.getName());
assertEquals(16, user.getAge());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is more or less correct. The only thing to be added is that both of the above tests can be used to test the test_function but if there is a inner service/function call and we want to check the value and also verify the class type of the arguments passed to the function, then the capture/Argument Captor is used.

So, in your example, when you use : capture(user), you would also want to check the values of the User object.